# How to prevent null return when initializing driver in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium

I need to prevent a "null" return when I initialize my driver class. Below is my code. Also, I need to check if the driver is null then initiate the driver if don't initiate the driver, instead keep the current initiated driver instance. Using java.

public class InitializeDriver {

```
private static WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeTest
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (null == driver) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path.to.driver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return driver;
}
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with this, does it throw any error ? why do you have `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` when you have already declare driver as a static and global variable ?   it should be just like `driver = new FirefoxDriver();`  in if block

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, yes I removed Webdriver before the driver and now it works fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you did it wrong.

`private static WebDriver driver = null;` driver --> class variables (static variables)

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` driver --> local variable (only access on this method)

They have different scopes, so when you use `driver` in other methods, you are using the first one, the static variable.

How to fix:

```
private static WebDriver driver; //default is null

@BeforeTest
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    
  // check null if you want to lazy creation, if not, just remove if()
    if (null == driver) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path.to.driver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Hi lucasnguyen17, yes I removed Webdriver before the driver and now it works fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to return if it is null?  You could wrap the null check in a `while`  loop until it properly initializes.